# Using next instead of break in comprehension list

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, list-comprehension

Considering a word, I'd like to search it in a dictionary, first as key and then as value.

I implemented in the following way:

```
substitution_dict={'land':['build','construct','land'],
                   'develop':['develop', 'builder','land']}
word='land'
key = ''.join([next(key for key, value in substitution_dict.items() if word == key or word in value)])
```

The idea is to take advantage of short-circuiting, the word is first compare with the key, else with the value. However, I'd like to stop when is found in the key.

Running the above snippet works good. However, when the `word` changes to other word not present in the dictionary, it throws `StopIteration` error due to the next statement which is not finding results.

I was wondering if this is doable in one line as I intended.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use `''.join()`?There only one element in your list.

Comment: I'd like to get the string from the key or values in the dictionary.

Comment: If the word isn't in the dictionary, *what exactly is supposed to happen*? Why not just catch the exception normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a default argument in [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).And `next()` would only return only one element,so `"".join([])` is unnecessary.

Code below:

```
key = next((key for key, value in substitution_dict.items() if word == key or word in value), None)
```

When the iterator is exhausted, it would return `None`.

Or if you really want to use it with `''.join`, like:

```
key = "".join([next((key for key, value in substitution_dict.items() if word == key or word in value), "")])
```